# Magento Product Configuration

Tags: magento

I'm working on an eCommerce website on the Magento Platform.

I'm trying to get an information icon to display next to the radio buttons, So when someone rolls over the icon it will show the associated product information in a rollover popup.

There is already [a website that does this](http://www.fiercepc.co.uk/gaming-pcs/goblin-amd-gaming-pc/#customise). As you can see all you have to do is rollover the I Button to see the product information.

Is this possible? any extensions out there to help me with this? Look forward to your replies! :)

Comment: I think there is no extension for your requirement. You need to customize the code

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea on where you can start.
The bundle product options are rendered by the files located in `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/` folder.

Each file corresponds to a type of option (select, multiselect, radio and checkbox).
You can'd do much about the select and multiselect types but you can customize the radio and checkbox templates.

In each of these 2 files you will see a `foreach` loop like this:

```
<?php foreach ($_selections as $_selection): ?>
    <li>....</li>
<?php foreach;?>
```

That is where the options are rendered.

The variable `$_selection` in this loop is the actual product that you can select.
You can call `$_selection->getShortDescription()` for example to get the short description of the product.

Keep in mind that not all the attributes are available for the `$_selection` variable.
If you want you can load the actual product and use that:

```
$_realProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($_selection->getProductId());
```

I don't actually recommend this because it can affect the performance. But if you don't have bundle products with a lot of options you can do it.

You can take the alternative and rewrite the method `Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type::getSelectionsCollection` and add more attributes to the collection.

Now if you have all the data you need the rest is css and js. Should be easy.